# Binding entire UserControl to a property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

My viewModel gets a UserControl from a service. I want to display that UserControl.

XAML looks like:

```
<Grid >
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding AddInUI}">

    </ContentPresenter>
</Grid>
```

And the ViewModel's property like:

```
public UIElement MyUI
        {
            get
            {
                return myUI;
            }
            set
            {
                Set(ref myUI, value);
            }
        }
```

So I fetch the ui and set to this VM's property. However, nothing renders in the UI. The getter of the MyUI property never gets called, even after I assign value to it, like:

```
MyUI = 'some user control';
```

Comment: Use a `ContentPresenter` instead of a `UserControl`.

Answer (score 0):

A `VM` would not contain a UI-specific element like this. It would however retrieve a `ViewModel` context for `MyUI` property and use a `DataTemplate` in the `XAML` to render that `ViewModel` `Type` appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and notify `MyUI` property in `set` of `MyUI` property.

Comment: It is already implemented and property is notified within the 'Set' method